# Docker swarm, list all container status

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have couple of nodes in docker swarm but both the nodes shows only container running on them when "docker stats" command is run

But i would like list container stats (cpu,memory) from all nodes when docker stats is run on any one of the node.

Is this possible?

Any insight will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to retrieve all container stats of a given service in a Swarm.

if you want information about CPU, memory and other info, you can use  combinations `docker node`, `cut`, `xargs` and ssh then `docker stats` on each node:

```
docker node ls | cut -c 31-49 | grep -v HOSTNAME | xargs -I"SERVER" sh -c "echo SERVER; ssh SERVER /usr/local/bin/docker stats --no-stream"
```

Above command will show you each container CPU,Memory group by node
like

**Node1**

```
b95a83497c91 awesome_brattain 0.28% 5.629MiB / 1.952GiB 0.28% 916B / 0B 147kB / 0B 9
e5c383697914 test-1951.1.kay7x1lh1twk9c0oig50sd5tr 0.00% 196KiB / 1.952GiB 0.01% 71.2kB / 0B 770kB / 0B 1
```

**Node2**

```
  67b2525d8ad1   foobar      0.00%     1.727MiB / 1.952GiB   0.09%   2.48kB / 0B         4.11MB / 0B         2
    4bda148efbc0 random. 0.00% 1.672MiB / 1.952GiB 0.08% 110kB / 0B 578kB / 0B 2
```

Also ref.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907274/docker-stats-in-swarm-mode

Answer (score 0):

this is nos possible with pure docker, or you could use CAdvisor tha make monitor on nodes from the cluster an get metrics form containers. If you wish you could also monitor those metrics with prometheus and grafana.